# Discord bot sending unwanted messages

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

I have a warn script where u basically warn duh and it works but every time it sends an unwanted message

[image: What is sends]

Here's my script

```
const db = require("quick.db")
execute(message, args, prefix){
    if(!message.mentions.users.first())
    {
        message.channel.send("Please specify a user to warn")
        return;
    }
    if(args[1]){
        if(args[1].startsWith("<")){
        message.channel.send("You can only warn one person at a time")
        return;
        }
    }
    if(!args[1]){
        message.channel.send("Please specify a reson for the warn")
        return;
    }
    let warned = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())
    message.channel.send(`${message.mentions.users.first}` + "You have been `warned` for " + args.slice(1).join(' '))
    if(!db.get(`WCount_${message.guild.id}_${warned}`)){
    db.set(`WCount_${message.guild.id}_${warned}`, 1)
    }else if(db.get(`WCount_${message.guild.id}_${warned}`)){
        db.set(`WCount_${message.guild.id}_${warned}`,db.get(`WCount_${message.guild.id}_${warned}`) + 1 )
    }
    message.channel.send(`${message.mentions.users.first()}, You now have ${db.get(`WCount_${message.guild.id}_${warned}`)} warns!`)
}
```

Am pretty sure its a bug but just to be sure I asked it here
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line, where you wrote `message.mentions.users.first`, you are appending the actual function's code instead of calling it:

```js
message.channel.send(`${message.mentions.users.first}` + "You have been `warned` for " + args.slice(1).join(' '))
```

You need to add parentheses after the function to make sure you call it:

```js
message.channel.send(`${message.mentions.users.first()}` + "You have been `warned` for " + args.slice(1).join(' '))
```